# Passing Variable to xrandr in bash

Tags: bash, centos, xrandr

I'm trying to pass a variable to xrandr so when the script runs, it will output the auto resolution.

```
#!/bin/bash
DISPLAY=$(xrandr | grep ' connected' | cut-d' ' -f1)
xrandr --output "$DISPLAY" --auto
```

Will output

> Can't open display DisplayPort-0

If I change the variable like below..

```
DISPLAY=DisplayPort-0
```

It will still throw the same error

It's only if I hardcode, or run the actual command like so...

```
xrandr --output DisplayPort-0 --auto
```

will it run as intended. Any thoughts? I find it puzzling why xrandr is not accepting variables in a bash script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlucky naming - `DISPLAY` is already reserved to point to the correct X server. Open up a new shell and check its contents:

```
$ echo $DISPLAY
:0
```

Use a different name for your `DISPLAY` variable. BTW, this is also why
it's recommended to use lowercase variable names in scripts so in your case it could be:

```
display=$(xrandr | grep ' connected' | cut -d' ' -f1)
```

Additionally, notice there may be more than 1 screen connected at the same time and in that case `xrandr --output "$display" --auto` would fail.

Comment: I'll keep in mind to use lowercase variables from now on, didn't know that!